# Dynamic onclick variable scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, onclick

I have a javascript function which runs onload. It finds anchor tags by class and adds an onclick function based on data in the tag. My problem is with the variable 'h' which contains part of the href. It will be set to whatever the last evaluation of this function is. So if the last value of h is "s-g123", all links on the page will have this as the value inserted into the link. How do I fix the value of h at runtime so is is static? Thanks in advance.

```
// converts <a href='#g123' class="shoh"> to <a href='#g123' onclick=function() { shoh( 's-g123', 'show') }">
function managelinks() {
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
var h, pos;
for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if ((elems[i].className).indexOf('shoh') > -1) {
        if ((pos = elems[i].href.indexOf('#')) > -1) {
            h = "s-" + elems[i].href.substr(pos + 1);
            elems[i].onclick = function () {
                shoh(h, 'show')
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: off: see querySelectorAll for more efficient querying (if you don't have to support IE6/7) Also read about JavaScript's closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: Thanks for the link on closures. It does seem to be the issue. There must be a way to accomplish my goal by restructuring this. The task seemed so simple... Also thanks for the querySelectorAll hint - looks like it can reduce the amount of code and maybe even speed things up.

Comment: See example below in my answer. I also used `anchor_elem.hash` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to support old retarded browsers, you could use something like this:

```
function managelinks() {
    // querySelectorAll should work with ie8+
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('a.shoh'), i;
    var h, pos, elem;
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elem = elems[i];
        h = elem.hash.substr( 1 );
        if ( h ) {
            // remember the value of h by making a closure
            elem.onclick = (function( myH ){
                return function () {
                    shoh( myH, 'show');
                };
            })( h );
        }
    }
}
```

If you were also using the jQuery library (or the much smaller ZeptoJS) then your function could be much shorter:

```
function managelinks() {
    $(document).on('click', 'a.shoh', function(){
        var h = this.hash.substr( 1 );
        if ( h )  shoh( h, 'show');
    });
}
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on/ , http://zeptojs.com/#on

Comment: Brilliant. I'm only supporting down to ie8 so no issue there. There is so much I don't know about javascript. It could take me a few hours to digest this. I haven't used hash either - will need to look into it as well. Thanks for the working answer and a lesson to boot.

Comment: Just curious, what part of your answer is not compatible with old browsers? Just the querySelectorAll?